# java.lang.SecurityException in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

When i am trying to run my application on emulator .splashActivity class is not called directly LoginActivity is called while when i run in my device trough usb it throws it the following exception,

This is a strange behaviour when I remove my LoginActivity splashActivity class is called and application closed as loginactivity is not found, and when I resume splash as MainActivity everything works fine

```
[2012-11-22 16:59:57 - medeclinicv2] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.kredence.medeclinicv2/.LoginActivity }

[2012-11-22 16:59:57 - medeclinicv2] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.kredence.medeclinicv2/.LoginActivity } from null (pid=5929, uid=2000) requires null
```

This is my Manifiest code, I have cleaned my project

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kredence.medeclinicv2"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".splashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            clearTaskOnLaunch = "true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".viewAppointment"
            android:icon="@drawable/minilogo"
            android:label="Schedule/View Appointment"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            clearTaskOnLaunch = "true">            
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".scheduleActivity"
            clearTaskOnLaunch = "true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">            
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".scheduleAppointment"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            clearTaskOnLaunch = "true">            
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".reScheduleAppointment"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            clearTaskOnLaunch = "true">            
        </activity>
      <!--  <service android:name=".MainActivity"></service> --> 
       <service android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.updater.UpdateService"/>
       <receiver android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.updater.WakefulReceiver"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

splashActivity

```
package com.kredence.medeclinicv2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class splashActivity extends Activity {

    protected int _splashTime = 5000;
    private Thread splashTread;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        final splashActivity sPlashScreen = this;
        // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
        splashTread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        wait(_splashTime);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {} finally {
                    finish();
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClass(sPlashScreen, LoginActivity.class);
                }
            }
        };
        splashTread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            synchronized (splashTread) {
                splashTread.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: show code where exception happens

Comment: Please clean your project and build again.

Comment: This is a strange behaviour when i remove my LoginActivity splashActivity class is called and application closed as loginactivity is not found, and when i resume splash as MainActivity every thing works fine

Comment: -Nik.... i have cleaned my project again still the same problem

Comment: –Yahor10 i have updated my answer

Comment: Noo idea guys what might be the problem??

Comment: please paste your LoginActivity code?

Comment: Try by giving full activity name (with package name) i manifest file as .com.kredence.medeclinicv2.splashActivity

Comment: – Sas when i include my package name in manifest file it doesnot give me any exception but, after splashActivity the project gets closed LoginActivity is not called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out your Android Manifiest Code.

Generally, `java.lang.SecurityException` is because you may enter two entries pointing to same activity. Remove the second one and you should be good to go.